# Get all buttons of a web page and delete the ones with certain background-image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, button, background-image

Good morning everybody, I'm a bit of newbie in javascript and other web languages.

What I want to do is get all buttons of a web page, then delete the one(s) with a specific background-image.

I understand the use of getElementsByTagName but can't do anything more.

I've started with the code above :

> document.getElementsByTagName(button)

What should I do next please ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What background-image do you want to filter by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the steps :

1. Get all elements
2. Check each element with specific background-image
3. Remove the element.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="parentNode">
    <button style="background-image:url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg')">First</button>
    <button style="background-image:url('http://www.allgraphics123.com/ag/01/14142/14142.gif')">Second</button>
    <button style="background-image:url('http://jitendravaswani.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/191356xcitefun-cartoon-pluto.jpg')">Third</button>
    <button style="background-image:url('https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WsZ4Q7Y156A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/vN1-gy0xZQU/photo.jpg')">Fourth</button>
</div>
```

**javaScript :**

```
var imageButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var parent = document.getElementById("parentNode");
for(var index = 0; index < imageButtons.length; index++ ){

    if(imageButtons[index].style.backgroundImage == "url(http://www.allgraphics123.com/ag/01/14142/14142.gif)"){
        alert();
        parent.removeChild(imageButtons[index]);
    }
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/6et6mhyf/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (buttons[i].style.backgroundImage == "specific image") {
                buttons[i].style.display = 'none';
            }            
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The buttons are located in classes so that :

    cursor.earn_pages_button.button_page_XXXX

I tried that : 

> document.getElementsByClassName('cursor earn_pages_button button_page_XXXX

I tried that :